# Interpretation of the density-density correlation function

Tags: correlation-functions

I'm trying to get a physical interpretation of the density-density function

$\mathrm{Cor}(r,r')=<\Psi^\dagger(r)\Psi(r)\Psi^\dagger(r')\Psi(r')>$

For example, when we have a optical lattice with bosons, described by a Bose-Hubbard Hamiltonian. In the Bogoliubov regime, we can calculate the correlation function w.r.t. to a thermal state $\rho_\beta$.

The first picture shows the correlation function for a small $\beta$, the second for a larger $\beta$. When we look at big distances, the correlation tends to 1. And for small $\beta$ the correlation function looks as expected, but for bigger $\beta$ the correlation function is smaller than 1 for small distances, what does that mean?

And what's the interpretation of $\rho(0)\rho(0)$? Find a particle at a site $i=0$, when there's already a particle?

Edit: mean density is equal to one.

[image][image]

Comment: Did you look at the connected correlation function: $\langle \rho(r) \rho(r') \rangle_c = \langle \rho(r) \rho(r') \rangle - \langle \rho(r) \rangle \langle \rho(r') \rangle_c$? It can be interpreted as the square of the variance of the density.

Comment: Are you working in units where the mean density equals unity? If so you should add that detail to the question. If not then there's nothing special about the number 1 here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @MarkMitchison: Yes, the mean density equals one. I edited the question. I'm not surprised by the value 1, but the values smaller 1 for the case of high temperatures (second pictures).

Comment: @QuantumMechanics If the second is for large $\beta$ that means *low* temperatures. If there is a repulsive contribution to the energy then one would expect anti-bunching, i.e. reduced probability to find two bosons nearby. And this effect should be more important for temperatures lower than the interaction energy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, sorry, I meant large values of $\beta$. That makes sense :-)